# Windows 7 : How to remove option to "Save Windows on external hard drive" upon plugging the drive

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Small question for an annoying issue :)
I have an external 3TB hard drive I use for storage (Western Digital). I use it with an older PC, Asus, on Windows 7.

When plugging the drive, there's a small standard Windows menu asking you what you want to do ("Open file explorer", etc). At some point, I've mistakenly clicked on "Save Windows on the drive", and now it keeps presenting this option every time I plug the drive. This is annoying, because due to lagging in display, sometimes I mistakenly click on it again, and it starts making a system save on the drive - which I *never* want to do.

I've tried emptying the drive and reformatting it, changing the file system (from NTSF to FAT32), but it doesn't make a difference : every time I plug it I get presented with that "Save Windows" option which I don't want.

So my question is fairly simple: how to completely remove that option for that specific external drive? (Note that it is not there for other drives for which I haven't made the mistake initially).

Screenshot attached (in French, but fairly self-explanatory).

Thank you very much for your assistance and ideas :)

[image]

Comment: This must be a translation error, because, I cannot find a single instance of the phrase "Save Windows on the drive" anywhere on the internet (except for this page). What exactly is saved when you select the option?

Comment: @Ramhound: "Exécuter une sauvegarde sur ce Iecteur" = "Run a backup on this drive".

Comment: [This](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) and using the Drive registry will reset what options are displayed.  It's locked behind a simple forum registration.  Disabling File History Backup and/or WIndows Backup will also likely solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last option in your dialog seems related to File History Backup.

If you have ever used this disk for backup, Windows will remember
its drive-letter (`F:`). You could try to change the drive-letter
of this disk in Disk Management.

Check also *Settings > Update & Security > Backup*, where you may disable
the option of "Automatically back up my files" to totally disable
File History.

If you wish to keep File History, you may still do finer tuning of it by
clicking on "More options" on the same page.

Comment: Thank you :) ...

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Comment: Done :) .......